# Integration testing of a Beam Pipeline

Tags: apache-beam

We have a Beam pipeline that is written using the Python SDK. The pipeline is reading from an ordered Pub/Sub topic, doing some small transformations and then inserting into ElasticSearch.

We want to write some integration tests that will cover the entire flow, reading from Pub/Sub and using the ES client, to make some assertions over what was inserted as a result. Since the job is streaming, it's a bit tricky to test it inside tests. Here is an example of how I do it now:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def test_options():
    setup_options = SetupOptions()
    standard_options = setup_options.view_as(StandardOptions)
    standard_options.streaming = True
    standard_options.runner = "DirectRunner"
    return standard_options



def test_reading_from_pubsub_to_elastic(test_options, customer_es_client, pubsub_publisher, user_events):
    expected_ids = ["1_3", "1_9", "1_4", "1_6", "1_10", "1_8", "1_5", "1_7", "1_2", "1_1"]

    p = HelpderClassToInitPipeline(pipeline=TestPipeline(blocking=False, options=test_options))
    pipe = p.create_pipeline(project=PROJECT, local_config=LocalConfig(run_local=False))
    pipe_result = pipe.run()

    futures = []
    for e in user_events:
        futures.append(
            pubsub_publisher.publish(
                topic=f"topic_",
                data=json.dumps(e).encode(),
            )
        )
    for f in futures:
        f.result()

    time.sleep(10)  # wait for the pipeline to consume events

    result = customer_es_client.search(index="customer", body={"_source": ["_id"], "query": {"match_all": {}}})

    ids = [d["_id"] for d in result["hits"]["hits"]]

    assert ids.sort() == expected_ids.sort()
    pipe_result.cancel()
```

We are using `pytest` as a test runner, and we run the inside the CI. Basically we provision Pub/Sub topics in CI, then run the tests, and then we clean up everything.

You can see that `time.sleep` call that is needed for the pipeline to consume and store so that we could query ES. Not sure if this is the best practice.

Any advices how can I improve this?

Comment: Hi, we have a similar scenario with integration testing. Instead of waiting/sleeping, we start polling the DB with a timeout. Also we use random generated events to publish and looking for them in DB, so parallel tests won't interfere with each other. Haven't found better solution yet.

Comment: Hmm, that's a nice alternative. Will look into how to do it as `sleep` is not really something I'm a fan of. Thanks